# Styling input text CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to create input text like below Image : 

[image]

First I used CSS3 with some help like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CXASb/4/) fiddle . because of problems with old browsers I reached to don't use CSS3.
Now I coded like this :

```
input[type=text]
{
    color: #979797;
    height: 28px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
        background-image: url('Pictures/Input-BG.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;

}
   <input id="txtScrictAddress" value="Your Adress (required)" type="text" />
```

Input-BG.png is this image : 

[image]

and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TGzng/1/) is the result.

1. Did I slice input image right ?
2. Input has a left border color , How should style the input in css like the image?

Comment: The image is good, add `border: 0;` to disable the default border style.

Comment: @Kapap Thanks, What about shadow on the left side of Input ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need to set a border radius and border to none. And edit your image so the dark thing is on the left side also.

```
input[type=text]
{
    color: #979797;
    height: 28px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbpVI.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-radius: 5px; /*up to date browsers support this, but you can add prefixes if you want*/

    border: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TGzng/8/

Comment: Thank you. 
It seems better than my code but I think still your sample has small different with Image that I putted. I mean the small shadow on the left of Input.

Comment: I used the image you supplied, the image needs to be edited to include the left part of the shadow.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use images to get something where both ends differ, you will at least need 2 images to get that. try to search for ["sliding doors input css"](http://www.google.de/#hl=en&q=css+sliding+doors+input). maybe [this topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678925/styling-an-input-button-using-sliding-doors) helps you out (but there are a million other examples out [in the web](http://www.google.de/#hl=en&q=css+sliding+doors+input) and on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sliding%20door%20css%20input&submit=search)).

Comment: Thank you. So you meant I should use two images , one for left and one for background , right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a border-radius to round the edges. This won't work pre-IE8 though.

```
input[type=text]
{
    color: #979797;
    height: 28px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
        background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbpVI.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border:1px solid #777;
    border-radius:5px
}
```

As for image slicing, easy way to get the left shadow part means you need to have a very wide image for the background. Or do that sliding doors thing the other person suggested.