# Sliding doors for input text

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to use the sliding doors css tehnique for input text? I've used it in 'button', but it doesn't seem to work with input types.

Comment: well, I ask theoreticaly, it's a simple input text with a custom class. In regular sliding doors button, there are 2 images: one is applied to the button (left) and the other one is applied to a span inside the button (right). Should I wrap the input in a div and try to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678925/styling-an-input-button-using-sliding-doors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the input tag inside of a span or div and then do the [sliding doors](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/sliding_doors.html) technique. If you don't want to add the extra tag, use multiple background images. It is important to note that this isn't supported by every browser.

About multiple CSS background images: http://css-tricks.com/css3-multiple-backgrounds-obsoletes-sliding-doors/

Comment: I'm trying to stay away from CSS3 beacause I want as much compatibility as I can get. I'll try putting the input in a div or span and will be back with the result.

Comment: it works in almost all browsers, still having issues with IE. I used a span and the input text inside it. Thanks!